# In what situations, the web browsers would complain the errors in the HTML?

Tags: html, parsing, firefox, browser

I don't have much experiences in writing HTMLs. 
As I know, some errors won't be complained by the morden web browsers, like:

```
<html>
<ol>
<li> ordered item 1
<li> ordered item 2
</ul>

<ul>
<li> unordered item 1
<li> unordered item 2
</ul>
</html>
```

Instead of reporting the mismatching error between `<ol>` and `</ul>`, it will render the page as below:

ordered item 1

ordered item 2

- unordered item 1

  unordered item 2

I am wondering:

Will web browsers render the webpage anyway, no matter what errors are there in the HTML?

i.e.

In which situations, the web browsers will complain the errors in the HTML?

Further, Is this no-error-reporting required by HTML5 specification?

Comment: Web browser is very forgiving, It will never complain.

Comment: HTML is an loosely typed language, Therefore if its compiler finds any  mistakes it assumes to be in format and do not report any Error.

Comment: Web browsers will simply try to make it work and won't complain about your sloppy code... unlike stackoverflow members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will web browsers render the webpage anyway, no matter what errors are
>   there in the HTML?

In the HTML serialization, modern browsers follow a parsing algorithm designed to be tolerant of mark up errors, and will render whatever it makes of the complete input stream.

In the XHTML serialisation, the parsing must follow XML parsing rules. This means that if and when it encounters a well-formedness error, it **must** stop parsing the input stream. The browser is **not** required to report an error (Firefox does, IE9 doesn't), and may choose to simply render whatever DOM it has built at the point where it had to stop parsing, and remain HTML5 conforming.

> In which situations, the web browsers will complain the errors in the
>   HTML?

Browsers do not, in practice, report errors, except for XML well-formedness errors when using the XHTML serialization, and then only sometimes. If they did, then they are telling the user, who is not the least bit interested in whether the author made a mistake when the page was written. All the user wants is access to the content.

> Further, Is this no-error-reporting required by HTML5 specification?

No it isn't. Browsers are entitled if they so wished to report such errors. The HTML serialization parsing algorithm is quite clear about when a error occurs. In the case of your mark up, the relevant rule says:

> **An end tag whose tag name is one of: "address", "article", "aside",
>   "blockquote", "button", "center", "details", "dialog", "dir", "div",
>   "dl", "fieldset", "figcaption", "figure", "footer", "header",
>   "hgroup", "listing", "menu", "nav", "ol", "pre", "section", "summary",
>   "ul"**
>
> If the stack of open elements does not have an element in scope with the same tag name as that of the token, then **this is a parse
>   error**; ignore the token.
>
> ...

Then the rules for handling parse errors does not require browsers to either report them or not report them. Validators are required to report at least one such parse error,

Comment: thanks, Alohci. Your answer is professional. I really enjoy it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this lies in the distinction between **HTML** and **XHTML**.

The key point to HTML5 is to have one specification to serve both as text/html and application/xhtml+xml. This addresses a number of historical issues with XHTML which were very pressing if one was getting into web development in 2005. I'll leave the research on that as an exercise for the reader.

If you are serving your HTML5 content as **XML** (i.e. using the mime type application/xhtml+xml) then you can expect clients to fail on parsing with an error:

```
XML Parsing Error: mismatched tag. Expected: </ol>.
```

Alternatively **if you just serve it as regular text/html, you can expect the standard undefined browser behaviour on poorly formed documents**.

I'd like to make it clear that broken html documents don't necessarily work when web browsers display them. Mismatched tags like that will usually cause the page to display strangely.